# How do I create an automatic polling service to keep data up to date in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, service, observable, polling

I am new to Angular and I'm having trouble figuring out how I can auto refresh service data with API requests set on an interval. This is the service in question, where I intend to update `shopPreferences` field on a given timer:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ShopManagerService {
    private shopPreferences: ShopPreferences = null;

    setPreferences(shopPreferences: ShopPreferences) {
        this.shopPreferences = shopPreferences;
    }

    isDeliverySlotsActive(){
        if(this.shopPreferences == null || this.shopPreferences.delivery_slots == null) return;
        return this.shopPreferences.delivery_slots;
    }

    getCurrencySymbol(){
       if(this.shopPreferences == null || this.shopPreferences.currency_display_symbol == null) return;
       return this.shopPreferences.currency_display_symbol;
    }
    ...
    // more data getters
}
```

As of right now, this `shopPreferences` field is being set upon the initilization of a certain component, using a separate `ApiManagerSerivce`, like so:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ApiManagerService {

    private token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6MjcwMjA3MiwidGltZXN0YW1wIjoiMjAyMS0wNC0wOSAwOToxNToxNS4';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    fetchShopPreferences(id: string) {
        const url = "https://commerce.ww-api.com/commerceapi/v1/front/front_url/" + id + "/";
        return this.http
            .get<ShopPreferences>(url, {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    token: this.token,
                }),
            });
    }
    ...
    // more api requests
}
```

How can I transform my code so that the `ShopManagerService` can handle the API request and keep the `shopPreferences` object up to date on a interval of - say - 2 minutes?

Comment: Where are you calling `fetchShopPreferences`?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz it's being called in one of my components. The component is injected with the `ShopManagerService` and `ApiManagerService`. This way I call `fetchShopPreferences` and `setPreferences` (I define a subscription for this). However, this property must not be set in this component as it should be set when the service is initialised, as well as kept up to date on a given period of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this, while removing your existing call to `fetchShopPreferences`. You would have to set the `id` property for the interval to know what to use for the fetch call (or if it's static just provide it directly as an argument):

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ApiManagerService {

    private token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6MjcwMjA3MiwidGltZXN0YW1wIjoiMjAyMS0wNC0wOSAwOToxNToxNS4';

    public id: string; // Update this where/when you need to

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private shopManagerService: ShopManagerService) {
      interval(120000).pipe(
        switchMap(() => fetchShopPreferences(this.id).pipe(
          first())
        )
      )
      .subscribe((res) {
        shopManagerService.setPreferences(res);
      });
    }

    fetchShopPreferences(id: string) {
        const url = "https://commerce.ww-api.com/commerceapi/v1/front/front_url/" + id + "/";
        return this.http
            .get<ShopPreferences>(url, {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    token: this.token,
                }),
            });
    }
    ...
    // more api requests
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I'm about to try your solution but I can't seem to grasp where I would call `setPreferences` so I can set the `shopPreferences` property. Would you mind clarifying this part?

Comment: @ManuelBrás Updated.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out in the meantime. Thank you good sir, your solution is working! Also, regarding the `id` field: this property would be set after the user logs in to his shop (think of it as an Uber Eats from the point of view of the owner of the shop). What would happen with the call inside the constructor while `id` is unset? Can I just use a `setId()` method when I get this property without a problem?

Comment: @ManuelBrás You don't even need a function to set it, just use the property directly. You can have a `filter` in the interval pipe before you run the fetch to check if the id is set. If it's not it will just skip it.

Comment: Or have a function and make the property private, to make your code more strict.